# getGridParam bringing data from first page only

Tags: jqgrid

***getGridParam*** is not working and its bringing data only from first page .I have used **loadonce :true** and my data type is **json**. Please help .It was working but it suddenly stopped working .

Any help will be apprecitaed.

Comment: If you want that one helps you then you should post more details what you do. Which version of jqGrid you use and from which fork of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7)? What you do exactly? Do you get `"data"` parameter with respect of `getGridParam`? In which part of your code (inside of which callback) you do this? You should include the JavaScript code, which you use, in the text of your question.

Comment: Hi , I am using 4.3.1 version.I am using free jqGrid.I am using this statement in  **loadComplete** callback ,   . 'var ids = orderGrid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'data');' This is the piece of code I am using .It returning only data for the first page

Answer (score 0):

I guess that the reason of the problem in the wrong implementation of the server code. If you use `loadonce: true`, then the server have to return **all data** instead of returning only one page of data. You should fix your server code and remove server side paging.

Moreover I strictly recommend you don't use retro versions of jqGrid, like version 4.3.1 published in 2011. The version 4.3.1 is dead and it's not supported since a long time. There are currently two main forks of jqGrid: [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/) (the current version: 4.13.4), which I develop, and commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) (in current version: 5.1.1). To try free jqGrid you can just modify three lines of HTML code, which loads jqGrid files. You can load there directly from CDN (see [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs)).

Comment: I agree that I need to change the version of jqGrid to latest one.But i wonder why **loadonce :true** is not bringing all data irrespective of witring this line ---> var ids = orderGrid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'data');

Comment: @heen0: jqGrid can return by `$(this).jqGrid('getGridParam', 'data')` only the data returned previously **from the server**. I suppose that you returns from the server (see the request to `url`) **only one page of data instead of returning all data**.